# Magento 2 Payment Method Billing Address Country

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods, magento2.2.2, billing-address

Can one only show/allow specific countries in the billing address form in countries drop down ?

See screen shot attached. I need only/available in E.G: **United Kingdom**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Country Options](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/country-options.html) at `Stores > Settings > Configuration` "*identify* the country where your business is located and *the countries from which you accept payment*."

Comment: I am not accepting payments in any other countries as I no payments for those store views has been setup, I am starting to think that there is no way to remove them from drop down from a settings perpective!

Comment: Hummm I got it what you meant  now. Under `United kingdom` store view I have in the Allowed Countries `Ireland` as well as `United kingdom`.  Each store view has it's own domain I am not sure why I am getting other Allowed countries under this UK store view/domain.

Comment: maybe you could update the question to describe your store views and which countries are allowed for each (and what is actually showing)?